# excel vba worksheet change function too slow?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a worksheet change function to give my excel spread sheet the illusion of a search bar with a drop down box containing the results of the text in the search bar.

before I just had the hide rows part of my code which would hide and then unhide some rows in my spread sheet containing the results. that worked fine but the results would sometimes be slow and not always show up until I re calculated them.

so I added calculate to the ranges and this unfortunately slows the whole thing down substantially. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Range("D11").Value <> "" Then
Dim xlpassword As String
xlpassword = "Perry2012"
ActiveSheet.Unprotect xlpassword

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
Worksheets("HOME").Range("A1").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("E33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("E32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("F33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("F32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("G33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("G32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("H33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("H32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("I33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("I32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("J33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("J32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("K33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("K32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("L33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("L32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("N33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("N32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("O33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("O32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("P33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("P32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("Q33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("Q32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("R33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("R32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("S33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("S32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("U33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("U32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("V33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("V32").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("W33").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("W32").Calculate

Worksheets("HOME").Range("D15").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D17").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D19").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D21").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D23").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D25").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("D27").Calculate

Worksheets("HOME").Range("M15").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M17").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M19").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M21").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M23").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M25").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("M27").Calculate

Worksheets("HOME").Range("T15").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T17").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T19").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T21").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T23").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T25").Calculate
Worksheets("HOME").Range("T27").Calculate



    Rows("15:28").Hidden = False
    Rows("34:36").Hidden = True
Else
    Rows("15:28").Hidden = True
    Rows("34:36").Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect xlpassword
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Would replacing all those separate lines by just one work:

```
Application.Calculate
```

it might be the case that you have some volatile functions heavily used in the workbook(i.e. TODAY()), which I reckon will make all formulas based on them re-calculate on each of those calculation lines in your code